# Issue resolving file with Object - array multis in Webpack

Tags: webpack

I have a Webpack config file which has the following entry point

```
entry: ['babel-polyfill', './app/index.js']
```

Which works fine but I also need a second bundle now to export some modules separately. I tried

```
entry: {
    bundle: ['./app/index.js', 'babel-polyfill'],
    exports: ['./app/exports.js']
}
```

but then I get the error

```
ERROR in multi babel-polyfill ./app/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app/index.js'
```

Why can't it now resolve this and is this even the right syntax for what I want to do?